# How to implement a smooth Zig Zag without bleeding?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

so I am trying to recreate this wave effect that I found online. Just like the original image: I want about four smooth ridges from the center, as well as have the circle (focal point) in which they are emanating, to be small. [original wave image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIx5l.jpg)

The problem is, when I try and apply the Zig Zag effect to the lines, it looks great when the points are on "corner," but when I turn it to the "smooth" setting, the middle part bleeds, so the focal point ceases to be small. Weirdly, to eliminate this issue, I can increase the amount of ridges. When I do that the middle stops bleeding and it's once again emanating from a small circle in the center, but I want this effect with only four smooth ridges. I'm not sure why it's looks great when set to corner, but not on smooth. Please help!

Before Zig Zag effect (my design on left, example on right):  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ugxlt.png

After Zig Zag effect (with corner ridges): [image]

After applying "smooth" ridges:
[image]
The center is now bleeding (no matter the size setting).

After increasing the ridge amount:
[image]
The center is now intelligible.

How do I create this with only around four smooth ridges, without the bleeding, like the example on the right?

Comment: Are the triangles generated via an effect as well or are they individual objects? If effect, tried expanding that effect first?

Comment: I used the rotate tool, then expanded the shapes, so every triangle is an individual filled object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a slightly different workflow

Start with a single white stroked line over a black background

give it the stroke profile you want

apply the zigzag effect to the single line

use the rotate tool and option click the bottom point on your original line

in the rotation field type in the degree rotation that you want (I did 360/24 or 15º)

press the copy button

press command+D to duplicate it repeatedly to complete the circle

[image]

Comment: Thank you, you saved me so many more hours of trouble!